# Want to grep in .tar.gz file in Solaris

Tags: bash, solaris

i have a file in .tar.gz format in solaris. i want to grep some line from that. i am using zipgrep command but unable to find the line. Below is my sample file and command that i am using.

Sample file:

BD201701.tar.gz

BD201702.tar.gz

BD201703.tar.gz

i am using below command to search a line that contains bangladesh.

```
zipgrep 'bangladesh' BD2017*
```

But it;s showing below error.

```
[BD201701.tar.gz]
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
the last disk(s) of this archive.
zipinfo:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of BD201701.tar.gz or
      BD201701.tar.gz.zip, and cannot find BD201701.tar.gz.ZIP, period.
/usr/bin/zipgrep: test: argument expected
```

Comment: `.tar.gz` is not `.zip`, and `zipgrep` doesn't support `tar.gz` apparently.

Comment: can you please tell me the command to find the line from the file..

Comment: You could extract the file using `tar`, display it's content with `cat` and then use `grep`.

Comment: is it not possible to do this by a single command

Comment: for one file you can do `gzip -d  - onefile.tar.gz | tar xf - | grep 'bangladesh'`

Answer (score 2):

`zipgrep` has been made for processing PKZIP archive files. In PKZIP archives the compression is applied individually on each contained file, so the process boils down to a sequence of operations like this **(not actual code!)**:

```
foreach file in archive:
    unzip file to tmpfile
    grep tmpfile
```

A compressed tar archive is different. First you pack a large bunch of files into an archive, and then the compression is applied to the whole bunch. So to search inside that the whole archive has to be unpacked first, i.e. something like this **(pseudocode again)**:

```
make and change to temporary directory
tar -xZf ${archive}
grep -R ${seachstring} ./
```

However a tar archive itself is just a bunch of files "glued" together, with some information about their filename and size inbetween. So you could simply decompress the archive into a pipe, disregarding file spearation and search through that

```
zcat file | grep
```

Answer (score 2):

`zgrep` does not work on solaris servers. In case the requirement is to find a pattern in a/all file(s) inside a directory given that the files are zipped, the following command can be used.

```
gzgrep 'pattern' filename
```

or

```
gzgrep 'bangladesh' BD2017*
```

Answer (score 1):

use zgrep:

```
zgrep 'bangladesh' BD2017*
```